# How to convert every parameter of a function to any specific type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have created a `clamp` function to bound value in a given range. *(Almost every one of you know what a clamp function does)*

So this the function I created (using `TS`)

```js
function clamp(value: number, min: number, max: number) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max)
}
```

but, there are some use cases where I want to get rid of converting all three `params` to `Number` type to pass it inside the function. I know I would have done something like this

```js
function clamp(value: number, min: number, max: number) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(Number(value), Number(min)), Number(max))
}
```

converting every single `param` to `Number` type.

**I want to know if there is/are any other way/ways where I can just convert every `param` to `Number` type at once??**

> *I am still looking for more easy answers!*

Comment: Since your function expects numbers `clamp(value: number, min: number, max: number)` I guess you are allowed to send arguments as numbers only, aren't you?

Comment: @Dalibor I did but let say an example an `element` (HTML) have an attribute **i.e.** `data-value` and if we want to use  that value we need to do `element.getAttribute('data-value')` right! And it will return the value indeed but the value will be of type `string` and in order to pass that value in the function I first need to convert it in number. But to save time _(it is not a lot time consuming process but it is what it is)_ I want the function to the work itself.

Comment: I'd use your first version of clamp and have the caller convert to number. `n = clamp(Number(a), Number(b), Number(c))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.map` to convert all values to `Number` at once. In plain old JS:

```js
function allNumbers(...values) {
  return values.map(Number).filter(v => !isNaN(v));
}

console.log(`${allNumbers(1,`26`, 42)}`);
console.log(`${allNumbers(...[...`123`])}`);
console.log(`${allNumbers(`20`, `+`, `22`, `=`, 42)}`);
console.log(`${allNumbers(...(`20+22=42`.split(/[+=]/)))}`);
```

Typescript ([see also...](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-abuxhh?file=index.ts))

```js
function clamp(...values: Array<number|string>) {
  const numbers: (number|Nan)[] = values.map(Number);
  if (numbers.filter(v => !isNaN(v)).length === 3) {
    const [value, min, max] = numbers;
    return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
  }
  return `insufficient argument(s)`;
}

console.log(clamp(42));
console.log(clamp(1,3,`42`));
```

Comment: But in my case there are only 3 `params`

Comment: Thanks! But I have a question what if we want to have named params for example `clamp({ number, min, max })`

Comment: Glad I could help ;). For 3 named arguments, I've modified the [Stackblitz snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-abuxhh?file=index.ts).